Monitors not recognized via Thunderbolt dock after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
After upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (kernel 5.15) to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (kernel 6.8) external monitors connected via Thunderbolt dock station (DisplayPort) are not recognized any more.
Hardware:

HP ZBook 15u G5 (Intel UHD Graphics 620)
HP Thunderbolt Dock G2
2x HP EliteDsiplay E232

However, the devil is in the details:

The dock station itself is recognized and peripherals connected to it work properly (LAN, keyboard, audio). boltctl reports connected and authorized dock.

If the laptop is started connected to dock station, screens get recognized and work properly. Once dock is unplugged and then plugged back, screens never work again (full restart is needed).

(Perhaps related) On startup disk encryption prompt is shown in low resolution and only on internal laptop screen. Before update it was mirrored onto all screens in FullHD.


So far all available system updates (including drivers and FW) are installed. Logs (journalctl and dmesg) don't show anything suspicious. Also tried different BIOS and kernel startup settings (e.g. pcie_ports=native), but no luck.
I'm looking for any hint which module might have a bug or is just left mis-configured after update.

The problem might not be related to Ubuntu per se, but rather to its kernel. The colleague of mine has exactly the same hardware setup and experience exactly the same problem on Archlinux (kernel 6.6).

